# JBL CSLM20 external Mic not recording audio on Ubuntu 20.04.03LTS desktop

Tags: 20.04, microphone

I recently bought JBL CSLM20 external mic. This mic comes with an ear piece which allows us to hear the audio recorded through mic. Somehow my Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS desktop is not recording sound from mic. Surprisingly if I talk into the earpiece, sound gets recorded.

Here are snapshots of Pulse Audio Volume Control

**Input Devices Tab**
[image]

I toggled Front Left to 0 that didn't resolve the problem.

**Configuration Tab**
[image]

**Snapshot of Alsa mixer Settings**
[image]

Same mic if connected with windows 10 laptop, records sound properly.

Comment: You're desktop certainly hasn't the combo connector this was designed for like phones, tablets and some laptops. So, obviously you need an Y-splitter to plug it separately to the audio out and mic in. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks but I do have a question. I am connecting my microphone to microphone port present at front panel. It has a separate headphone port in which I do connect headphones which work properly. Do I still need to use Y Splitter?